# My C++ code gives error which is not seen in code. Whats the bug?

Tags: c++, oop, syntax

When I compile this code, it gives a runtime error shown below. But it doesn't tell which line is faulty in my code.

> Debug Assertion Failed!
>   Program: C:\Windows\system32\MSVCP110D.dll
>   File: c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xstring
>   Line: 1143
>   Expression: invalid null pointer
>   For information on how your program can cause an assertion failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.
>   (Press Retry to debug the application.)

The following is my C++ code. Consisting one base class: `Vehicle` and another derived class: `Car` which is publicly inherited from the base class.

```
class Vehicle {

private:
    string VehicleNo, color;

public:
    Vehicle():VehicleNo(NULL),color(NULL){};
    string getVehicleNo(){return VehicleNo;}
    string getColor(){return color;}

    void setVehicleNo(){
        //getline(cin,VehicleNo);
        cin>>VehicleNo;
    }

    void setVehicleColor(){cin>>color;}
};



class Car: public Vehicle {

private:
    int distance;

public:
    void setDistance(int x){distance=x;}
    void setCarNo(){setVehicleNo();}
    void setCarColor(){setVehicleColor();}

    int calculateFare(int x){return 5*x;};


    void displayInformation()
    {
        cout<<"Your Car Number is: "<<getVehicleNo()<<endl;
        cout<<"The color of your Car is: "<<getColor()<<endl;
        cout<<"Total fare which you have to pay: "<<calculateFare(distance);

    }


};

int main()
{
    Car c1;
    int distance;
    char choice;

    cout<<"Enter car number: ";
    c1.setCarNo();

    cout<<"\nEnter Car Color: ";
    c1.setCarColor();

    cout<<"\nHow long would you like to go? Enter distance in kilometers: ";
    cin>>distance;
    c1.setDistance(distance);

    cout<<"\n----------------------------------\n";
    c1.displayInformation();
    cout<<"\n----------------------------------\n";

    cout<<"\nDo you want to calculate Fare of different distance (y/Y for yes and another character for No?  ";
    cin>>choice;

    do{

        cout<<"\nHow long would you like to go? Enter distance in Kilometers: ";
        cin>>distance;
        cout<<"\n----------------------------------\n";
        c1.setDistance(distance);

        c1.displayInformation();

        cout<<"\nDo you want to calculate Fare of different distance (y/Y for yes and another character for No?  ";
        cin>>choice;
    } 
    while(choice=='y' || choice=='Y');
}
```

Comment: [tag:c] and [tag:c++] are different languages, be careful with the tags when you ask.

Comment: Do not post images unless the nature of the problem requires them. About the error: use a debugger.

Comment: Why are you initializing variables of type `std::string` with `NULL`s?

Comment: Compile for debug, run in the debugger, when it breaks open the pane that shows the current call stack, click  on the line that's in your code.

Comment: I'm sure you did **"Press Retry to debug the application"**, didn't you...?

Answer (score 4):

C++ provides 9 `string` constructors: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string

Of these 2 of them accept pointers:

1. `basic_string(const CharT* s, size_type count, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator())`
2. `basic_string(const CharT* s, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator())`

When you call `VehicleNo(NULL)` and `color(NULL)` you are only passing a null pointer and not a `count` to the `string` constructor so the compiler passes your null argument into option **2**. Where `s` is expected to be:

> A pointer to a character string to use as source to initialize the string with

When the `string` constructor attempts to dereference `s` to copy it's contents into the `string` being constructed it segfaults.

What you're trying to construct here is an empty `string`. C++ already does that when you use the default constructor: `string()`.

A member object's default constructor will be called if no construction is specified in the constructor intialization list. So you won't need to put either `VehicleNo` or `color` in the constructor intialization list to construct them as empty `string`s. Meaning you can use the compiler's generated default constructor, and get rid of your constructor all together.

Comment: "it segfaults" - More precisely, the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Isn't reading from `NULL` always a segfault? Your comment seems to imply that's not the case. That there may be a case where `NULL` is read from but only an undefined behavior, not a segfault, is incurred.

Comment: What I meant to say was that passing a null pointer to those two constructors is already undefined behaviour. The fact that the constructor will read from the argument (and thus crash) is then just an implementation detail. Then again, reading from a null pointer is also always undefined behaviour.

Comment: @ChristianHackl You seem intent on declaring this undefined behavior, probably cause you understand something I don't. You make the statement that `string(NULL)` is undefined behavior. But you explicitly *do not* call that a segfault. Where exactly would the undefined behavior occur here and where would the segfault occur?

Comment: A segmentation fault is merely one possible manifestation of undefined behaviour. The undefined behaviour occurs at the moment you pass a null pointer to the constructor because the requirement of the pointer pointing to a valid char array is not met; undefined behaviour is not tied to low-level operations (if that's what you mean with "where exactly").

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is this line of code

```
Vehicle():VehicleNo(NULL),color(NULL){};
```

VehicleNO and color are of type string. They can't be NULL. Change it to something like this

```
Vehicle() :VehicleNo(" "), color(" "){};
```

Comment: I would just get rid of it as the compiler provided constructor is all that is needed.

Comment: Why initialise them to one-space strings?! Why initialise them with a char array at all? Why initialise them *manually* at all when the compiler will correctly do everything for you?